# How to compare a datetime object to a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to write a program to keep track of the errors. I am storing the first time an error occured and the last time. If the error continues to occur for 45 seconds, I will create an alert but the alert is not the part of my question.

I need to write an if statement to compare 2 datetime objects and take the difference in seconds. Then, if the difference is more than 45 seconds, I will create an alert.

My issue is I couldn't find out how to compare the difference between two datetime objects to a certain amount of time.

All the examples on the web including other StackOverFlow questions are just doing comparisons like `if today < yesterday: do something` but that doesn't help me because I don't know what will be one side of the comparison.
The time objects I am dealing with are as follows:

```
errors[oneEquity]['StartTime'] = 12:32:44
errors[oneEquity]['LastTime'] = 12:32:50
```

I found out from other questions that I can get the difference as follows:

```
errors[oneEquity]['LastTime'] - errors[oneEquity]['StartTime'] = 0:00:06
```

I believe that the difference is a datetime object, too. Now, I need to compare that object to 45 seconds but I don't know how to state 45 seconds.

Is it going to be a datetime object? If so, how can I create a datetime object of 45 seconds?

The if-statement I should write is something like that:

```
if errors[oneEquity]['LastTime'] - errors[oneEquity]['StartTime'] > (45 seconds):
    # create an alert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

error_occurs = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=45)
# error_occurs = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=44)
if datetime.now() - error_occurs >= timedelta(seconds=45):
    print('works')
```

** delta could be constant

Comment: Thanks @Ozballer31, that was really helpful. 

So, is the difference between two `datetime` objects is a `timedelta`? 

Also, I first had an error using `datetime.now()`, I had to use `datetime.datetime.now()`. Then I noticed that `import datetime` was not enough to use `datetime.now()`. When I added your import line `from datetime import datetime`, it worked fine. Why just importing datetime wasn't enough to use `datetime.now()`?

Comment: @Cagri datetime is module that contains datetime class, this name of module just confusing